# Entity Framework: after SaveChanges returned object doesn't have children

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I save an object in the database and then retrieve the saved object, it shows all null subobjects.

I use Entity Framework 6 and I have always used the queries as shown in the example below and it has always worked correctly, but I do not understand why this query shows the null subobjects.

```
public car save_car(car data)
{
    if (data.id_car == 0)
    {                
        _contextDrag.car.Add(data);
        _contextDrag.SaveChanges();                          
    }
    else
    {
        _contextDrag.SaveChanges();
    }

    return data;
}

public car get_car(long id_car)
{            
    car data = _contextDrag.car.FirstOrDefault(a => a.idCar == id_car);            
    return data;
}
```

Comment: it seems that you are new in .Net world, please have a look to code convention for new posts https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solution I applied in my project and it works correctly.

I have used `System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached`

```
public car save_car(car data)
{
    if (data.id_car == 0)
    {                
        _contextDrag.car.Add(data);
        _contextDrag.SaveChanges();
        _contextDrag.Entry(data).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
    }
    else
    {
       _contextDrag.SaveChanges();
    }

    return dades;
}

public car get_car(long id_car)
{            
   car data = _contextDrag.car.FirstOrDefault(a => a.idCar == id_car);            
   return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you reuse your `_contextDrag` for multiple operations. When you call `save_car` - saved car is stored inside context. When you then call `get_car` - the **same** car instance is returned. If it had all child properties null (for example is was new entity you were adding) - it will still have all child properties null, and lazy loading will not work, because it's exactly the same entity you had in `save_car`. As usual best way is not to ever reuse your context.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so far never had problems with using the same _context and performed the same kind of processes, first saved an object and then retrieved it again.

Comment: Well you were lucky, but if you continue doing that - you will experience much more suprising and difficult to debug problems.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have sort of the same issue but I can't seem to figure out why.

When I use _context.SaveChanges() at the end of my DataInitializer it throws a custom error that I wrote for the setter (code down here) of an object in another object.

```
        public Locatie Locatie
        {
            get => _locatie;
            set
            {
                if (value is null)
                    throw new ArgumentException(Settings.locatieLeeg);
                else
                    _locatie = value;
            }
        }
```

However, if I get rid of the error it just goes to the next setter that also checks for null. This leads me to believe that all my subojects of an object are set to null. This wasn't a problem before and now it is, I'm not sure why to be honest.

Any theories?

EDIT: The output of the console gets stuck here:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (52ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 100), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 100), @p3='?' (Size = 6), @p4='?' (Size = 100)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [Locatie] ([Gemeente], [Huisnummer], [Land], [Postcode], [Straat])
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4);
      SELECT [LocatieId]
      FROM [Locatie]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [LocatieId] = scope_identity();
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (31ms) [Parameters=[@p5='?' (Size = 320), @p6='?' (DbType = Int32), @p7='?' (Size = 14)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [ContactPagina] ([Email], [LocatieId], [Telefoonnummer])
      VALUES (@p5, @p6, @p7);
      SELECT [ContactPaginaId]
      FROM [ContactPagina]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ContactPaginaId] = scope_identity();
```

ANSWER:

I somehow managed to fix it, but I don't know how. I cleaned up my ApplicationDataInitializer class, made changes to my mappers, repositories and split properties that were objects of my classes into different declarations and saved them one by one. All of this somehow managed to fix it, but I don't know what.

Comment: Have you updated the db connector?
I once had problems of this type when I updated the Mysql.Data.Entity connector.
I finally had to go back to an earlier version.

Comment: This was not the case actually. Thanks for your answer.